# Exception -- Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, exception, int, solution

i'm trying to find my very first steps in java and while developping the code below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MoyEcart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float moy= 0, ecart_type= 0, somme= 0, carre= 0, moy_tmp, part_one;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Dernier terme de la suite:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        float[] t= new float[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            System.out.print("Terme " + i + ":");
            t[i] = sc.nextFloat();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            somme+= t[i];           
        }
        moy = somme/n;
        moy_tmp = moy * moy;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            carre += t[i] * t[i];  
        }
        part_one = carre/n;
        ecart_type=(float) Math.sqrt(part_one - moy_tmp);
        System.out.println("Moyenne ="+moy);
        System.out.println("Ecart type="+ecart_type);
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error, and i couldn't find a solution to it, so please if you guys now a way out to this, i'll be grateful.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException 
  at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) 
  at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) 
  at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2345) 
  at MoyEcart.main(MoyEcart.java:17)
```

Comment: You should consider formatting your code, for readability. And regarding your problem: Learning to debug is part of learning to program. Your next challenge is probably to understand the stack trace. I wrote a [beginner's guide](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/) that might help.

Comment: Could you put an example of your input?

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace you are getting as well as what you are typing in the Console at the prompts?

Comment: "Input" means what you type on the console and the program reads and proceseses.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
     at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
     at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2345)
            at MoyEcart.main(MoyEcart.java:17)

Comment: Let me hazard a guess here: you are using French locale but entering the number as "10.2", or using US locale, but entering the number as "10,2" (French notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code, and it works fine for me! You should first enter a single number and press enter. After that, you need to input that amount of numbers one at a time. This means you need to press enter after every number. The output I got from your program looks like this:

```
Dernier terme de la suite:3
Terme 0:1
Terme 1:2
Terme 2:3
Moyenne =2.0
Ecart type=0.8164965
```

Comment: yes it does. The first number has to be an integer because you're calling nextInt(). But the others work as being a float.

Comment: It doesn't work with floats, i tried it. try to give numbers with comma, the exception will appear again

Comment: You can't use commas after the numbers. Try it again, but press enter after every number.